# update total count on entry add,delete and update with ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3 and creating an expenditure maintenance app.
In this each entry has expenditure amount field and i am adding/deleting/updating it via ajax successfully.
But I am trying to refresh total Amount value whenever any add,delete edit operation is done.

Look at my code:

delete controller function:

```
def destroy
    @expenditure = Expenditure.find(params[:id])
    @expenditure.destroy

    **@total = Expenditure.where(:user_id => current_user.id).sum('amount')**
    //@total calculated and to be updated in view

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(@expenditure) }
      format.js  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

After an expenditure is deleted I do this:

```
$('.delete_post').live('ajax:success', function() {  
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
    **$("#totalBox").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'total' , :locals => { :total => expenditures.calculateTotal })).html_safe %>");**
});
```

index View:

```
<div class="blocks" id='**totalBox**'>
    <%= render :partial => 'total' , :locals => { :total => @total }%>
</div>
```

total partial:

```
Summary
<hr/>
<div class="actionItems">
    Total Expenditure <> <span id='totalexp'><%= total %></span>
</div>
```

In the near future I have to pass more values to this partial like 
last month expense,
friend1 expense,
friend2 expense,

Please help me solve this?
Also suggest an approach to solve this type of issue?
I am a new-bi
Help // SOS

Comment: Are you trying to refresh it in the view, the database, or both?

Comment: question updated; description added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move this line of code from common js file to destroy.js, in the views directory under the appropritate controller directory. Based on you description most probably it would be `app/views/expenditure/destroy.js.erb`

```
$("#totalBox").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'total' , :locals => { :total => @total })).html_safe %>");
```

Also remove the `head :ok` from `format.js` just leave it as `format.js`

Comment: The key is `total` is dynamic data and you need to keep it dynamic and not put it in a common js file under public folder which is loaded only once.